# How to call rest api in express js

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I am new in nodejs and I am using express js, I am calling REST API and want to show the response, but my problem is that the response is showing in console.log but I want to pass the body(response) in assistant.ask, where I am wrong here is my code:

```
var request = require('request');
let rawInput = function (assistant) {
    let rawInput = assistant.getRawInput();
    request.post(
    'http://xxxxxxx.ngrok.io/api/v1/240/respond',
    { json: { query: rawInput } },
    function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

         console.log(body);
         assistant.ask(body);               
        }
    else{
        console.log(error); 
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: share us your full code, and explain what assistant actually does.

Comment: @BearNithi: everything is fine, i just want to know that how can i pass(get) response in google assitance ? means whats wrong with following line

assistant.ask(body);

Comment: do you get any error?

Comment: @BearNithi: no i am getting result successfully in console.log but i just want to pass response in google assistant ,how can i do this ?

Comment: are you posting the same question from two accounts?